# How to handle the master server going down in a master-slave log server architecture?

Tags: logging, server, architecture, master-slave

I am building a Log service.

I have a master and some slave servers. The slave servers directly receive logs from the client. Each interval time, slaves will push the logs to the master server to store. But the problem is when the master goes down, then after some time, it wakes up, but I have already lost the logs in the interval that the master goes down.

Has anyone built a service like this? Please share your idea.

[image: Master and slave server]

Answer (score 1):

The common way of making a system resilient to outage is to implement a queue.  Slaves will write logs to a queue and the master server reads from the queue.  If the master goes down, the queues persist until the master recovers.

With this approach you may not need the slaves.  Each application can write directly to the logging queue with an async fire-and-forget request.